# JavaScript touchend on dynamically shown element doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, touch, dom-events

I noticed a strange behavior in touch events. The situation is like that: I have a `#pointercapture` div, which is hidden by default. A `touchstart` handler is attached to the body, which causes `pointercapture` to show (overlays the body). The `pointercapture` has `touchend` event attached, which hides it. The issue is that on `touchstart pointercapture` appears and on `touchend` it doesn't hide. You have to touch screen and release once more for this to disappear. 
Here's the fiddle. I have also attached mouse events, which work as expected (`pointercapture` hides on first `mouseup`). 
https://jsfiddle.net/3p8eyug5/

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="pointercapture"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:green;
}
#pointercapture {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:orange;
}
```

JavaScript

```
  var $=jQuery;
$('body').on('touchstart mousedown', function(e) {
    $('#pointercapture').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#pointercapture').on('touchend mouseup', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can someone explain this behavior? I'm also curious how it works with pointer events and touch, I have no way to check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Once the body captures the touchstart event it holds the entire touch action through touchend (The touch event is not transfered to #pointercapture when it appears). You just need to put the touchend event on the body instead of #pointercapture and it should work as you describe.

```
$('body').on('touchstart mousedown', function(e) {
    $('#pointercapture').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('body').on('touchend mouseup', function(e) {
    $('#pointercapture').hide(); // also change this to #pointercapture
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3p8eyug5/1/

Comment: Thank you. Actually the way it happens is useful to me, I was just curious how it works. Do you know if it's the same case for pointer events?

Comment: @Iron96 It is. The event flow is held by the originator in both cases.